# How to make a one-sided test for proportion in R

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, proportion, pooling

I've to make some tests for proportions in R because of some A/B duties. I know that given s1, sc the number of success of two samples and n1, nc the total number of experiments, I can do this for H0: s1/n1 = sc/nc

```
prop.test(c(s1, sc), c(n1, nc), conf.level=.95, correct=FALSE, alternative='two.sided')
```

to get the confidence interval of the difference p1 - pc (when p=s/n) and the p-value.

What about if I need to test H0: p1 - pc <= 0? I tried this but I'm not sure it's correct:

```
 prop.test(c(s1, sc), c(n1, nc), conf.level=.95, correct=FALSE, alternative='greater')
```

Is it ok to check this way? How can I calculate the test statistic under pooled variance assumption?

Comment: it seems i can use the latter expression for that test, but still I don't know: is it possible to use the pooled variance for a test statistics like p1-pc? anf Ha:p1-pc>0?

Comment: That's how I'd test against an alternative of greater-than, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging a bit, I'm pretty sure my assumptions were correct and that's the right syntax, so the answer. However the pooled variance cannot be used because p1 != pc. It's possible to use this statistic instead x = p1 - pc and test against H0: x < 0. The prop.test can then be exploded in this formal calculus:

```
# H0: p1 - pc <= 0
# Ha: p1 - pc > 0
alpha <- .005
z <- qnorm(alpha, mean=0, sd=1, lower.tail=FALSE) # not alpha/2 because it's one-sided
z_unpooled <- (p1 - pc)/sqrt(p1*(1-p1)/n1 + pc*(1-pc)/nc)
p_value_unpooled <- pnorm(-abs(z_unpooled))
z_unpooled > z ? # you can reject H0
```

Please let me know if my answer is wrong. Many tnx

Comment: "*However the pooled variance cannot be used because p1 != pc*" -- not so. Under the appropriate null, the population proportions are equal. It doesn't matter that the null distribution is wrong under the alternative.

Comment: Tnx for your comment, Glen. In the second case (one-sided, greater then) H0 is not p1 = pc, but p1 - pc <= 0 ---> pi <= pc. Under this null, shall we still say the proportions are equals?

Comment: Actually, the condition under which the null distribution of the test statistic is actually computed is $p_1=p_c$. Try computing it under your null and you'll see why.

Comment: It's not 100% clear, i must admit. Saying the null is pc < p1 is == to say pc = p1, actually?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment. The specification of the null as both "<" and "=" is a logical consideration  -- some people include "<" in their null, but the null distribution of the statistic is evaluated at "=".

Comment: ok, now i understood :)